# Exclude some URL paths to open the apps? (Deeplinking - Ionic2)

Tags: android, ionic2, deep-linking, applinks, deeplink

I want to exclude some URL paths to prevent them open the apps because the content is not available for the Android app.

**Below is my example URL and action:**

> http://www.example.com/   (open app)
>
> http://www.example.com/path/to/content    (open app)
>
> http://www.example.com/pathto/content (open app)
>
> http://www.example.com/pathtocontent  (open app)
>
> http://www.example.com/help   (do not open app)
>
> http://www.example.com/contactus  (do not open app)

How can I do this? Is there any way?

Comment: Use pathPrefix or pathPattern attribute as described in https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html#path